# How do I include the test TypeScript libraries in a test helper with Jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I want to include a test helpers file at ./src/index.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { NotificationContext } from "../state/NotificationContext";

export function wrapComponentInContext<T = {}>(Comp: React.FunctionComponent<T>, props: T = {}) {
  const mockSetter = jest.fn(() => { });

  const mockContext: ContextDefaultValue = ["context", mockSetter];

  return (
    <NotificationContext.Provider value={mockContext}>
      <Comp {...props}/>
    </NotificationContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

But because the file does not have the .test.tsx extension it complains about jest not being defined.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. Do not place test-specific code in production.

The sane (and only practical) solution is to move your helper to a different file (if you have a `/test` directory, it should be there), and `import` it directly from your test files that need it.